# UIStoryboardSegue - performSegue method passing the class rather than identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

I'm trying to perform a segue programatically (since apparently a segue action and an IB action don't work well together). I am therefore setting up an IBAction to do some stuff, and then send the performSegue method. The only performSegue* method I can find is "performSegueWithIdentifier:" which isn't what I need since I have a custom segue which is a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue.

Is there a way of passing a class as a segue programatically (like in IB where you can set a class as a segue rather than an identifier)?

Comment: what do you mean for "passing a class as a segue"?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by triggering segues **manually**. Select File Owner and give an identifier to manually triggered segue. Then you can also pass anything you like in prepare for segue method.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ChooseAPlayer"]) {
        chooseplayer = [segue destinationViewController];
        chooseplayer.serviceReceiver = ForNextScreen;
    }
}
```